# Will two graphs be isomorphic in this case?

Tags: graph-theory

I wanted to know whether two graphs will be isomorphic when the neighborhood of all the points of the graph are not same even through the geometrical structure of the graphs are the same.

Here's an example

[image: Graphs with vertices having different neighborhood and same geometrical structure]

Comment: What do you mean with "neighbourhoods of all the points .. are not same"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have added a link to a photograph showing what I am asking ?

Comment: From your image, it looks like you would like to know about the difference between labelled and unlabelled graphs. All three graphs correspond to the same unlabelled graph (the 3-line) but are different labellings of that graph

Comment: @gilleain Is labelling necessary for a graph ?

Comment: Depends what you want it do! A graph is often a representation of some kind of real-world structure. If you want to represent vertices with different labels, then you need a labelled graph. Otherwise, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you can find some mapping between the vertices that gives you that:
*vertices are adjacent in one graph if and only if the mapped vertices are adjacent in the other graph*
then the graphs are isomorphic. In the case of your diagrams, there is a vertex of degree $2$ which can be mapped across the graphs (and the degree-$1$ vertices can be mapped in either way, giving two different mappings between each pair - but you only need one for isomorphism). Here are a couple of isomorphic representations of $K_{3,3}$ with the vertices labelled to show a mapping:

[image]

[image]